# Ошибка OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument при выполнении

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, на `ubuntu` выполняется нормально, на `windows` выдает ошибку.

Код:

```
openfile = open('name.txt')
for line in openfile.readlines():
    myfile = open(line + ".txt", mode='w')
    myfile.write("text " + line.strip() '\n')
    myfile.close()
```

При выполнении на `windows` выдает:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'TEST00000\n.txt'
```

Comment: Если в файле name.txt одна  строка, то код выполняется

Comment: Очевидно что если нет строк имя файла нормально не составить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже на то, что ошибка в указании имени файла появляется из-за литерала `\n` в конце строки `line`. И ещё у вас отсутсвует конкантенация `line.strip() /n`. Попробуйте так:

```
with open('name.txt') as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        with open(line.rstrip() + ".txt", 'w') as myfile:
            myfile.write('text {0}\n'.format(line.strip()))
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @jfs Хорошо, просто так лучше видно что именно не так было в коде. В следующий раз постараюсь учесть все недочёты, спасибо за совет :)